# Is S3 bucket still guarantees 99.99% availability, in the event of complete region outage and without replication enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What would happen to a S3 bucket, created in one region , without any replication, if that region goes down. Does AWS automatically manages to take a backup to some other region. Or in other words, how does AWS guarantee that 99.99% availability and 11 9's durability in such events. Or is that the responsibility of the user to maintain replications across other regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When data is stored in Amazon S3, it is replicated to **multiple disks in multiple Availability Zones** (which means multiple Data Centers). That's how they offer 11x9s of Durability (the chance of keeping your data).

Note that this **Durability is higher than the 4x9s of Availability** (the chance of being able to *access* your data). This is because multiple AZs might become unavailable, but your data is not lost and would be accessible when an AZ becomes available again.

From [Data protection in Amazon S3 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/DataDurability.html):

> Amazon S3 provides a highly durable storage infrastructure designed for mission-critical and primary data storage. S3 ... stores objects on **multiple devices across a minimum of three Availability Zones in an AWS Region**. An Availability Zone is one or more discrete data centers with redundant power, networking, and connectivity in an AWS Region. Availability Zones are physically separated by a meaningful distance, many kilometers, from any other Availability Zone, although all are within 100 km (60 miles) of each other. ... These services are designed to handle concurrent device failures by quickly detecting and repairing any lost redundancy, and they also regularly verify the integrity of your data using checksums.

Basically, Amazon S3 keeps more 'backups' than you would normally keep in your own data center. Plus, rather than being 'backups', they are actually 'live copies' of the data so there is no need to 'restore' data in the case of a device or AZ failure.

To protect against **accidental deletion of data** you can activate Versioning, which keeps a copy of files that are overwritten or deleted (additional storage charges apply). Or, to protect against **malign intentional of data**, you could then choose to use **S3 Replication** to copy data to another AWS Account such that one person does not have permission to delete data from *both* AWS Accounts. You can also **replicate data to another Region** if you fear a whole Region becomming unavailable (Netflix does this).